# How to slice a big list of zip values into a two lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a biglist of zip values. I want to slice them into a two separate lists.

```
biglist = [(1.913, 0), (13.06, 22), (24.041, 36), (34.972, 50)]

[list1,list2] = biglist

Output: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am expecting following output as

```
list1 = [1.913, 13.06, 24.041, 34.972]
list2 = [0, 22, 36, 50]
```

How to obtain this?

Comment: `list1 = []; list2 = []` then `for x,y in biglist: list1.append(x); list2.append(y)`....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you can do that by `list1 = [x[0] for x in biglist]` and `list2 = [x[1] for x in biglist]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [16]: biglist = [(1.913, 0), (13.06, 22), (24.041, 36), (34.972, 50)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

In [17]: list1, list2 = zip(*biglist)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [18]: list1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[18]: (1.913, 13.06, 24.041, 34.972)

In [19]: list2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[19]: (0, 22, 36, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But how to get `[ ]` for list1 and list2? Now it has `( )`.

Comment: @Msquare `list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*biglist))`

Answer (score 1):

using lambda for

```
biglist = [(1.913, 0), (13.06, 22), (24.041, 36), (34.972, 50)]
[list1,list2] = [[x[0] for x in biglist], [x[1] for x in biglist]]
```